# Scope on empty association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, scope, associations

I'm trying to create a scope looking at empty association.

I've 4 classes : `User`, `Idea` `Project` and `UserJoins`.

More than one user can have the same idea or the same project.

I would like to create a scope to isolate users without ideas.

## Idea.rb

```
has_many :user_joins
has_many :users, through: :user_joins
```

## Project.rb

```
has_many :user_joins
has_many :users, through: :user_joins
```

## User.rb

```
has_many :user_joins
has_many :ideas, through: user_joins, source: :imaginable, source_type: 'Idea'
has_many :projects, through: user_joins, source: :imaginable, source_type: 'Project'

scope :without_ideas, ->{
  # I'm stuck here.
}
```

## UserJoin.rb

```
belongs_to :imaginable, polymorphic: true
belongs_to :user
```

I'm using `Rails 3.2.17` and `Ruby 2.0.0`

Does anyone have an idea to solve this ?

Answer (score 5):

You can include `user_ideas` and then check for a null id.

```
scope :without_ideas, ->{
  includes(:user_ideas).where(user_ideas: { id: nil })
}
```

This will left join `user_ideas` and then match only `users` which have not included a `user_idea` entry at all (because there wasn't one to join in).

Comment: Thank you, that's working as I said on my previous comment but I simplified too much my problem. I've edited my post with the polymorphic association that really stop me finally.

Comment: I've something like that `includes(:user_joins).where(user_joins: {imaginable_id: nil, imaginable_type: 'Idea'})` but it's not possible to have a `type` without an idea. Basically I think instead of asking for `Idea` I would have asked for `not Project` but it's not that good if I add more imaginable models in the futur. What do you think about that? Thank you in advance.